# How to get data from Dao class and set the controller class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

how to get data from Dao class in using the list> in controller

no

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/log"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String login(HttpSession session, String username, String password) throws Exception {

    Register r =new Register(username, password);
    List<Map<String,Object>> list=rdao.GetUserData(r);
    Member member=list.get(1).get("username").equals("password");

    if(member !=null) 
    {
    session.setAttribute("MEMBER", member); 
     return "taskform";
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("invalid user name or password");
    }
    return "loginup";
}
```

RegisterDao

```
  public List<Map<String,Object>> GetUserData(Register r) { 
      String sql="select *from user where username='"+r.getUsername()+"' and '"+r.getPassword()+"'"; 

      System.out.println("UN:"+r.getUsername());

      return template.queryForList(sql); }
```

hello, i get data in registerdao to controller but not get in data

Comment: First of all please follow java convention and rename your method to have the method name starting in lower case letters.Can you please explain what the issue is . Cannot understand your question properly.Are you not able to autowire the dao bean ?

Comment: rdao is a autowired

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ? Can you provide the stacktrace ?

Comment: member class was not import